# System with two equations - need brackets

Tags: equations, brackets

I want to make a system with two equations but with biggest numbers, because now I can't see the number in the paper and my teacher will not see well.
The system is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amstext}
\begin{document}
$$\left\{    
\begin{matrix}
I_1=I_2+I_3+I_4\\
I_3=I_5+I_6\\
\end{matrix}\right.
\Leftrightarrow
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
\frac{5-u_A}{1\times10^3}=\frac{u_A-4}{2,2\times 10^3}+
\frac{u_A-u_B}{4,7\times 10^3}+\frac{u_A}{4,5\times 10^3}\\
\frac{u_A-u_B}{4,7\times 10^3}=\frac{u_B}{6,8\times10^3}+2\times10^3
\end{matrix}\right.$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post complete code. `$$` ought not to be used in LaTeX. It is 20+ years deprecated.

Comment: Load [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and use `\dfrac` or `\displaystyle\frac`.

Comment: @cfr If I can't use `$$`what can I use for the same function?

Comment: @CarmenGonzález See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 8):

Something like this? Note the use of (a) the `array` package and `array` environments, (b) the use of (typographic) struts so that the rows in the first `array` line up with the ones in the second `array`, (c) curly braces to encase the commas that serve as decimal markers and (d) `\addlinespace` to provide a bit more whitespace between the rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amssymb,booktabs}
\newcommand{\tallstrut}{\vphantom{\frac{5_A}{4,10^3}}} % a typographic strut

\begin{document}
\[
\left\{
\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle\tallstrut}l@{}}
I_1=I_2+I_3+I_4\\ 
\addlinespace
I_3=I_5+I_6
\end{array}
\right.
\Leftrightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}l@{}}
\frac{5-u_A}{1{,}0\times10^3}=\frac{u_A-4}{2{,}2\times 10^3}+
\frac{u_A-u_B}{4{,}7\times 10^3}+\frac{u_A}{4{,}5\times 10^3}\\ \addlinespace
\frac{u_A-u_B}{4,7\times 10^3}=\frac{u_B}{6{,}8\times10^3}+2\times10^3
\end{array}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: As @egreg has noted in a comment, the same output may be achieved -- with slightly less typing -- by employing `dcases` environments (provided by the `mathtools` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,booktabs,mathtools}
\newcommand{\tallstrut}{\vphantom{\frac{5_A}{4,10^3}}} % a typographic strut

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{dcases}
I_1=I_2+I_3+I_4\tallstrut\\
\addlinespace
I_3=I_5+I_6\tallstrut
\end{dcases}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{dcases}
\frac{5-u_A}{1{,}0\times10^3}=\frac{u_A-4}{2{,}2\times 10^3}+
\frac{u_A-u_B}{4{,}7\times 10^3}+\frac{u_A}{4{,}5\times 10^3}\\ \addlinespace
\frac{u_A-u_B}{4,7\times 10^3}=\frac{u_B}{6{,}8\times10^3}+2\times10^3
\end{dcases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's works! I will use your code.

Comment: I'd give a try to `dcases` from `mathtools` instead of the complicated `array` construction.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I've provided an addendum to show how the same output may by achieved with `dcases` environments instead of `array` environments.

Comment: @Mico How I can put the brackets aligned at the left of the page in all lines? With the array environments.

Comment: @egreg How I can put the brackets aligned at the left of the page in all lines? With the array environments.